# How to install postfix/virtual domains/without mysql authentication

Tags: centos, postfix, dovecot

I want to install postfix and configure it for virtual domains on centos.
Recently, I configured postfix and it works fine with system users files `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`.

but I want to make dovecot and postfix authentication not on system users or mysql databases. I would authenticate users with some files same as `/etc/passwd` as proftpd authenticate.

is there a chance?

Comment: Please clarify: You don't want Dovecot/Postfix authenticate against system files, but you want use `/etc/passwd` for authentication? This is a system file. Or do you want to use a file similar to `/etc/passwd`, possibly the same file  you use for FTP authentication?

Comment: for more clarify, it means i want use a file for authentication, but don't use /etc/passwd file. or i don't want every body that has a mail on this system can login on the server (i know /sbin/nologin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So then just do it.

Postfix does not do authentication at all. It delegates to the auth mechanism which can be cyrus-sasl or dovecot: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_dovecot_comm

As you already use Dovecot, you should use it for authentication. The solution you want is extensively described in the manual: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/PasswdFile